Como se puede modificar el nombre de un modulo en odoo 16?
me gustaría cambiar el nombre de el modulo de Facturación a recibos o algún otro nombre, ya he podido modificar desde el propio odoo algunas partes que dicen esta palabra a recibo, sin embargo en el menú principal, en la sección donde dice facturas que esta acompañada por el botón de nuevo, subir y exportar todo no encuentro forma de cambiarlo, según vi en un vídeo se podía modificar cambiando esta sección desde código.
  <record id="action_move_out_invoice_type" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Recibos</field>
        <field name="res_model">account.move</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,kanban,form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="view_out_invoice_tree"/>
        <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_account_invoice_filter"/>
        <field name="domain">[('move_type', '=', 'out_invoice')]</field>
        <field name="context">{'default_move_type': 'out_invoice'}</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
          <p class="o_view_nocontent_smiling_face">
            Create a customer invoice
          </p><p>
            Create invoices, register payments and keep track of the discussions with your customers.
          </p>
        </field>
    </record>

este código lo saque del archivo account_moves_views.xml que se encuentra en la carpeta de vistas del modulo account, en donde dice recibos antes decía invoices, lo modifique actualice el modulo y sigue diciendo facturas, luego encontré otro similar pero en donde decía invoices decía bill.
    <record id="action_move_in_invoice_type" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Recibos</field>
        <field name="res_model">account.move</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,kanban,form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="view_in_invoice_bill_tree"/>
        <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_account_invoice_filter"/>
        <field name="domain">[('move_type', '=', 'in_invoice')]</field>
        <field name="context">{'default_move_type': 'in_invoice'}</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
          <p class="o_view_nocontent_smiling_face">
            Create a vendor bill
          </p><p>
            Create invoices, register payments and keep track of the discussions with your vendors.
          </p>
        </field>
    </record>

pero ocurrió el mismo caso, si alguien pudiera decirme si hay alguna forma de cambiar esa parte se lo agradeceria mucho.

reiniciaste el servidor???

como se hace eso?

tienes acceso??? si no preguntale al encargado ...
